# Activities in Vancouver for my visiting sister

Tags: canada, family, language, socializing

I am an expatriate in Vancouver, BC, Canada (PhD candidate at UBC). I would like to invite my little sister to spend a summer (probably in 2016) with me and my wife at Vancouver.

My little sister is a teenager. She's living in Switzerland and she has (almost) never left the country. Her mother tongue is French and she is learning English (and German and Portuguese) at school. In English, she is able to make very simple sentences but is not able to have a conversation. I would like to consider her stay as a good opportunity for her to improve her English.

I can think of thousands of things we can do together during the weekend. The issue is that I will not have plenty of free time during the week to do things with my sister. I am asking for **general advice in order to plan my sister's weekday activities**.

- Could you give me recommendation of activities and several days trips/camps that take place during the weekdays and that she could do without me?
- Do you know good associations that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 3):

Summer day or resident camps. Museums, schools, others may have specialty camps.

If it was earlier in the year, she might have been able to get a place as a counselor-in-training, although her English skill might not be enough.

Look for a summer program for international students to improve their English.